# Showing ProgressDialog in AsyncTask only for specific parameters

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm implementing an AsyncTask, that calls a WCF service methods in the doInBackground method.

the WCF method name is a parameter for the doInBackground method.

I want the progress dialog to show only for specific methods name sent to doInBackground.

My porgressdialog setting are set in onPreExecute methods.

Any way to make progressdialog appear for a specific doInBackground parameter (wcf method name)

```
public class WCFHelper extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String[]>{

private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://url";
final ProgressDialog pd;
public Context ctx;



public WCFHelper(Context _ctx)
{   this.ctx = _ctx;
    pd = new ProgressDialog(_ctx);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setMessage("login...");
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

}

@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String WCFmethod = (String)params[0];
    Map<String,Object> parameterArgs = (Map<String,Object>)params[1];
    Boolean isArr = (Boolean)params[2];

    String [] Fail = {"Fail"};
     String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/"+WCFmethod;
     String METHOD_NAME = WCFmethod;
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry: parameterArgs.entrySet())
               request.addProperty(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());         

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        if(!isArr)
        {
            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();               
            String[] toReturn = new String[1]; 
            toReturn[0] = result.toString();
            return toReturn;
        }
        else{
            envelope.implicitTypes = true ; 
            SoapObject listDataSet = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;         

            int numOfStrings = ((SoapObject)listDataSet.getProperty(0)).getPropertyCount();
            String[] toReturn = new String[numOfStrings];    

            for ( int i = 0 ; i <numOfStrings; i++) {  
                toReturn[i] = ((SoapObject)listDataSet.getProperty(0)).getProperty(i).toString();   
            }  
            return toReturn;
            }
        }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return Fail;
      } 
}

 protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
        // TODO: check this.exception 
        // TODO: do something with the feed     
        if(this.pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();


    }
```

As you can see one of the params for doInBackground is WCF method name.
I want the progressdialog to show only to specific WCF methods (received as parameter)

Comment: can we have code please?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Code can be added to code only and I can't find any here.

Comment: your question is vague. do post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom constructor of the AsyncTask to transfer necessary parameter for handling the progress dialog.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 

    public MyTask(boolean showProgress){
     ....
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send parameters also during instantiating the WCHelper object.

Keep a variable in the WCFHelper class.

```
public class WCFHelper extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String[]>{
    int val;
    public WCHelper(int param)   //constructor
    { 
        super();
        val = param;  //now you can use this val in onPreExecute
    }
...
}
```

Send the same parameter you wanted to send to onPreExecute(). For example,

```
WCHelper task = new WCHelper(param);  // this sends value to constructor
task.execute(param);  //this sends value to doInBackground
```

Comment: can onPreExecute() get parameters? how do i send it parameters? when i call wcfhelper.execute(params) can i use those params in onPreExecute method before doInBackground is starting?

Comment: No it cannot. But the only function that gets executed before onPreExceute is the constructor. So passing a parameter to the constructor will make it available for the onPreExecute().